# Apple Automater URL selection,

Tags: macos, automator

I want to search a website, say google, and open the search result weblinks. In Automator you just start by opining the search site witch the parameter in the url. Than you get all the links from this site and then you sort them.
BUT i never could find out HOW you stop after say the first 10 links. Cause there are sometimes 500 links and to open them all is too much.

So how i can stop the automator after he gave me the first 10 links ?

Thanks for answering

elekro

Answer (score 0):

It's a variant of the question you asked, but does this help you?

http://homepage.mac.com/cjrtools/automator-apps/files/url-links-textedit.html

Specifically "only return the URLs in the same domain as the starting page" might be of use.